# For what reason there is PlatformID.MacOSX?

Tags: c#, macos, unix, operating-system, environment

`Environment.OSVersion.Platform` returns a `PlatformID` ([Info: MSDN PlatformID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/3a8hyw88%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).
This PlatformID's value can also be "Unix" or "MacOSX".

My question is - for what reason are these values implemented? I thought .NET wouldn't run on MacOSX or Unix systems?! I know that there is Mono for example and in my mind it would make sense if this were/is implemented in Mono. But why in MS .Net which won't run on Unix systems anyway?

Comment: Silverlight, which has a very .NET-like Runtime and is an official Microsoft product, runs fine on OSX - and does return "MacOSX" when used in Silverlight.

Comment: @vcsjones - if you write your comment as answer, I'll will accept it, so that this question can be "officially" marked as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight, which has a very .NET-like Runtime and is an official Microsoft product, runs fine on OSX - and does return "MacOSX" when used in Silverlight.

Comment: I was hoping Microsoft implemented that to help with Mono compatibility.